# Generating dll from an existing code on Windows using CMake and VS

Tags: c++, cmake, sdk

I have downloaded an SDK written in C++ (OPC UA) that creates a .exe file on compiling with Visual Studio 2015. It has a bunch of CMake files. How could one see if it is possible to generate a .dll from such an SDK? Do the CMake files have this information or should there be any macros inside the headers I would have to search for ? The SDK has Visual Studio sample projects (.sln) that I am using to create .exe. 
The CMakeLists.txt looks like this

```
project(uasdk)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.0 FATAL_ERROR)
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH})
set_property(GLOBAL PROPERTY USE_FOLDERS ON)

include(CMakeDependentOption)
include(MessageUtils)
display_project_header("true")

if (EXISTS "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src")
    add_subdirectory(src)
endif ()

if (EXISTS "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/examples")
    add_subdirectory(examples)
endif ()

# set CMAKE_INSTALL_MESSAGE to LAZY by default to hide 'Up to date' output when building INSTALL target
if (NOT ${CMAKE_VERSION} VERSION_LESS "3.1")
    set(CMAKE_INSTALL_MESSAGE LAZY CACHE STRING "")
    set(CMAKE_INSTALL_MESSAGE_VALUES "ALWAYS;LAZY;NEVER")
    set_property(CACHE CMAKE_INSTALL_MESSAGE PROPERTY STRINGS ${CMAKE_INSTALL_MESSAGE_VALUES})
endif ()
```

The questions that already have been asked regarding this topic are from the people who are writing their own code. I intend to use the code from the SDK. Apart from changing the CMAKE file to include the dll do I need to make changes in the source code as well?

Comment: Is this an open-source SDK? Can you share the website/repository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It has a bunch of CMake files. How could one see if it is possible to generate a .dll from such an SDK? Do, the CMake files have this information or should there be any MACROS inside the headers I would have to search for ?

If the CMake project generates a library, then the statement *add_library* must appear somewhere. Note, however, that hierarchies of CMakeLists.txt files are possible, for example, the CMakeLists.txt you included adds two subdirectories. Consider the CMakeLists.txt files in there as well. Since an executable is generated, a call to *add_executable* must appear somewhere as well.

> I intend to use the code from the SDK. Apart from changing the CMAKE file to include the dll do I need to make changes in the source code as well?

I am not familiar with this SDK, but I would guess that examples contains the sources for the executable and src contains the sources for a library. If you just want to try something out, you can modify the example code or add a new example. In this case, you only have to modify the CMakeLists.txt in the examples directory (i.e., add your new source code file).

If you want to use the SDK as external dependency, check whether there is a FindNameofmySDK.cmake included in the CMake modules list or whether there is a NameofmySDK-config.cmake somewhere in the SDK sources or your installation. In this case, you can create a CMake project for your application and use *find_package* to look for the SDK.